# multiple mean_sdl with smooth plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean, confidence-interval

How could I plot `p7` and `p6` altogether in the same output, where m7 and m6 are obtained by melting different datasets? thanks in advance

```
p7 <- ggplot(m7,aes(x=time,y=value)) +stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_sdl", geom = "smooth")
p6 <- ggplot(m6,aes(x=time,y=value)) +stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_sdl", geom = "smooth")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
p7 <- ggplot(m7,aes(x=time,y=value)) +stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_sdl", geom = "smooth")
p6 <- p7 + stat_summary(aes(x=time,y=value), fun.data = "mean_sdl", geom = "smooth", data = m6)
```

Comment: That's exaclty what I wanted to do. Thanks a lot! I've still got a lot to learn :)